# Does rectangular matrix product left inverse rule out a "partial" right inverse?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, matrix-equations

Given a $n$-x-$d$ matrix (with $n>d$) $A$ whose columns are linearly independent, does there exist another $n$-x-$d$ matrix $B$ that satisfies both

$$B'A=I_d$$

(where $I_d$ is a $d$-x-$d$ identity matrix)

and

$$BA'=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 &0 \\ 
0 &  1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

Assume both $A$ and $B$ are full rank with non-zero real valued entries.